# How to restart networking with www-data

Tags: 12.04, server

I have a website which is changing configuration file in `/etc/network/interfaces`
But `www-data` cannot restart networking.
How do that?

```
Ubuntu Server 12.04
```

Answer (score 2):

Adjust your concept, also regarding safety / reliability aspects.

If it is *really* justified that your *website* needs to adjust system configuration, you'll want to contact e.g. a´self-written daemon process which provides a suitable amount of protaction and is specialised *only* in applying *limited* changes.

You do definitely *not* want to grant super user rights to your web server.

[Edit]

To be clear, your web server should also *not* write files in /etc/network/ because that alone requires that you change permissions there, which is not such a good idea. Your daemon process must coordinate this, also wrt potential race conditions.